# How can I disalbe all button&input templately in blazor server-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Now I have a CSS3 animation(not a full-screen animation) to show on my page.

When the animation is playing, I wanna disable all the button&input.

After the animation is finished, then enable all the button&input.

How can I achieve this? I don't want to add a boolean "IsEnabled" in each void to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listener the [animationstart and animationend event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp). Then, in the animationstart event, disable the button by using the "disabled" property. In the animationend event, enable the buttons.

Sample code as below:

```
<style> 
    #myDIV {
        margin: 25px;
        width: 550px;
        height: 100px;
        background: orange;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        from {
            top: 0px;
        }

        to {
            top: 200px;
        }
    }

    @@keyframes mymove {
        from {
            top: 0px;
        }

        to {
            top: 200px;
        }
    }
</style>  

<div id="myDIV" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to start the animation.</div>
<div class="btn_group">
    <input type="button" value="Submite" onclick="alert('click')" class="btn btn-info" />
    <input type="button" value="Crete" onclick="alert('crete')" class="btn btn-light" />
</div>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      
    // Start the animation with JavaScript
    function myFunction() {
        x.style.WebkitAnimation = "mymove 4s 1"; // Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
        x.style.animation = "mymove 4s 1";     // Standard syntax
    }

    // Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
    x.addEventListener("webkitAnimationStart", myStartFunction);
    x.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", myEndFunction);

    // Standard syntax
    x.addEventListener("animationstart", myStartFunction);
    x.addEventListener("animationend", myEndFunction);

    function myStartFunction() {
        this.innerHTML = "animationstart event occured - The animation has started";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "pink";

        //find the elements and disable them.
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].disabled = true
        }
    }


    function myEndFunction() {
        this.innerHTML = "animationend event occured - The animation has completed";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
        //find the elements and enable them.
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for this purpose.

In js you can get all elements by class and add disabled attribute to them:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("buttons-to-disable").disabled = true;
```

and to enable them:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("buttons-to-disable").disabled = false;
```

To call the js, you can use [IJsRuntime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1)